# couldn't upload the image in symfony

Tags: symfony

I'm trying to upload an image to a directory i get this exception, waiting for your answers , appreciate it.

here is my controller :

```
    public function addClubAction(\Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request $request)
    {
        $club = new Club();
        $form = $this->createForm(ClubType::class,$club);
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if($form->isSubmitted())
        {
            $dir="C:\\wamp64\\www\\iSchool\\web\\image";
            $file=$form['logo']->getData();
            $club->setLogo($club->getNom().".png");
            $file->move($dir,$club->getLogo());



            $em= $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $em->persist($club);
            $em->flush();
        }
        return $this->render("@Club/Club/addClub.html.twig",array('form'=>$form->createView()));
    }
}
```

here is the form :

```
class ClubType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('nom')
                ->add('type')
                ->add('description',TextareaType::class)
                ->add('logo',FileType::class,array("data_class"=>null))
                ->add('ajouter_club',SubmitType::class);
    }
```

This is the error code I get:
Call to a member function move() on null

```
$dir="C:\\wamp64\\www\\iSchool\\web\\image";       
$file=$form['logo']->getData();  
$club->setLogo($club->getNom().".png");            
$file->move($dir,$club->getLogo());      // the problem is here it tells 
$em= $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();        
$em->persist($club);
```

[exception :](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Bko2.png)

Comment: could you add the error code as a code in the body of your message instead of the link ? clicking on it takes us out of stack and it is bad for indexing this question in the future.

Comment: Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\
FatalThrowableError
in src\ClubBundle\Controller\ClubController.php (line 30)
             * @var UploadedFile $file             */            $dir="C:\\wamp64\\www\\iSchool\\web\\image";            $file=$form['logo']->getData();            $club->setLogo($club->getNom().".png");            $file->move($dir,$club->getLogo());            $em= $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();            $em->persist($club);
ClubController->addClubAction(object(Request))

Comment: there is a photo btw just click it and it will take u to the exception

Comment: Please [use text, not images/links, for text--including tables & ERDs](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Use images only for what cannot be expressed as text or to augment text. Include a legend/key & explanation with an image. Please clarify via edits, not comments.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use VichUploader bundle : https://packagist.org/packages/vich/uploader-bundle

You'll be able to upload your images in no time, handle the name of the file, the upload path, the preview, the Type for the upload and you have security.

Check it out, it's worth it.

Comment: thanks man, i'll try this out ! but does it works on symfony 3.4 ?